# unable to load settings from editor.codeinsight.xml , ui.inf.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

After Re-opening android studio , while building process is going on  it says that 
unable to load settings from .AndroidStudio2.3\config\options\editor.codeinsight.xml,ui.inf.xml and it says to recreate the file, whats wrong is going on with it and whats the reason .
sometimes all my Java and XML code is replaced by some TODO code generated by android studio and i need to rewrite the code once again why is this happening all the time, even  I've  tried to set my corrupted workspace as suggested in another question, But what is this why do this happen every time i open android studio

Comment: When did it start happening? Did you update android studio recently?

Comment: It may be caused by the corrupted file system (perform disk check) or the faulty RAM (run http://www.memtest86.com/).

Comment: @H.Brooks No brother i started developing from 2.3 version itself and it started after my first signed apk generation